# How to use dynamically if statement php

Tags: javascript, php

I have multiple enquiry forms and have different fields. I want to check validation for each field I have in different forms with ajax

Below is my example code:

```
if($name && $email && $mobile && $departuredate && $vehicle && $query){     
    ?>

  <form action="<?php echo DOMAIN; ?>contact/booking-form.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />

    <input type="hidden" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $mobile; ?>" />

   <?php if(isset($_POST['vehicle'])) {?>
    <input type="hidden" name="vehicle" value="<?php echo $vehicle; ?>" />
   <?php } ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="departuredate" value="<?php echo $departuredate; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="query" value="<?php echo $query; ?>" />

    <input type="hidden" name="enquiry" value="<?php echo $enquiry; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $page; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="agree" value="<?php echo $agree; ?>" />

    <input type="hidden" name="submit" id="submit">

  </form>

<script>
var form = document.getElementById('submit').form;
var submit_method = document.createElement("form").submit;
submit_method.call(form);
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

In given code $vehicle is not fix (sometime this value is blank). How can I check if form has vehicle field then check empty and proceed

Comment: use if(empty($vehicle)){ } like this

Comment: can you exlain with complete if line?

Comment: you want check value empty or not is it ?

Comment: no, on top of this code i have validation of empty fields coding but in given first line if statement i have to check if all fields have value then proceed , and $vehicle is dynamically field, so how can check this. can i take all fields in array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this same `if` statement in your javascript

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['vehicle'])) {?>
    //if the field exists write your js validation otherwise . . .
   <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

- List all the fields
- Gather all the required fields
- Validate
- If all validated, process the data

booking-form.php

```
<?php
    // Fields
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $departuredate = $_POST['departuredate'];
    $vehicle = $_POST['vehicle'];
    $query = $_POST['query'];

    // other fields

    // A set of required fields
    $required_fields = array(
        $name, $email, $mobile, $departuredate, $vehicle, $query
    );

    $message = [];
    $is_ok = 1;

    // Validate
    foreach ($required_fields as $each) {
        if (empty($each)) {
            $message[] = 'Fields with (*) are required';
            $is_ok = 0;
        }
    }

    // If all validated
    if ($is_ok) {
        // process the data
    }
?>
<ul class="errors">
    <?php
        // Display errors in list
        foreach ($message as $each_msg) {
            echo "<li>$each_msg</li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $mobile; ?>" />
    <?php if (isset($_POST['vehicle'])) { ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="vehicle" value="<?php echo $vehicle; ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="departuredate" value="<?php echo $departuredate; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="query" value="<?php echo $query; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="enquiry" value="<?php echo $enquiry; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $page; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="agree" value="<?php echo $agree; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script>
    var form = document.getElementById('submit').form;
    var submit_method = document.createElement("form").submit;
    submit_method.call(form);
</script>
```

Comment: not work for me,
i have these fields dynamic as per forms fields  
    ` // Fields
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $departuredate = $_POST['departuredate'];
    $vehicle = $_POST['vehicle'];
    $query = $_POST['query'];`

Comment: i have 3 steps to submit form with only validation via ajax  
  
1 - main html form  
2 - check validation via ajax on html form page  
3 - if validation success then submit form via ajax to mail send script  

but on main html form page has different fields like one form has 5 fields and two form has 6 fields

Comment: i just want to know how can i make Dynamic `if($name && $email && $mobile && $departuredate && $vehicle && $query){'

Comment: it'll make the page to reload after the ajax request

Comment: plz once read my code, after ajax validation if valid then redirect to booking-form.php page with post values  
everything is working but i want dynamic if() statement,

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use like this.

```
<?php

function function1() {
echo "this is function 1";
}

function function2() {
echo "this is function 2";
}

if ($page)
eval("{$page} ();");

echo "<a href='$PHP_SELF?page=function1'>Function 1</a>";
echo "<a href='$PHP_SELF?page=function2'>Function 2</a>";

?>
```

Comment: but i have to check fields value